# Element not visible with ruby and selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code for my element:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Search
                    </button>
```

I have identified the element like this:

```
 browser.find_element(:xpath, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary']")
```

it seems that I have more than one class btn btn-primary and the element is not visible on page - this is the error message I get. I have tried using an explicit wait as well but it doesn't work. I think I should define this element in another way. Any ideas how I should do this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use more than one property to identify an element:

```
browser.find_element(:xpath, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and @type='submit']")
```

With more html code we could help you more. If that is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one "Search" button? This may work, if your button takes a moment to show up.

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
search_button = wait.until { driver.find_element(:xpath => "//button[contains(text(),'Search')]") }
search_button.click()
```

(Edit: oops, posted Java)